# Realm Error: Property requires a protocol defining the contained type

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have the following model and I'm using `Realm`:

```
@interface GUIRoutineModel : GUIModel # GUIModel is a subclass of RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateModified;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;

@property NSInteger userId;
@property int routineId; #also have same issue using NSInteger


@end
```

When I call:

```
   // Persist to Realm DB
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        [realm addObject:routineModel];
    }];
```

I get the following error:

```
'Property 'routineId' requires a protocol defining the contained type - example: NSNumber<RLMInt>.'
```

I have  tried changing the `routineId` property to `NSNumber<RLMint>`, but that didn't work either. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is another version of the model that I have tried:

```
@interface GUIRoutineModel : GUIModel

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateModified;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;

@property NSInteger userId;
@property NSNumber<RLMInt> *routineId;

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried this:  `@property NSNumber *routineId;`?  NSNumber is an object pointer, so you'll need the c-style `*` object dereference.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels yes, I have tried that.

Comment: Looking at this a little closer, I don't think you can use a generic type annotation like `<RLMint>` on an `NSNumber` in objective-c; only collections like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are supported.  You could try declaring your property directly as an untyped `NSNumber`:  `@property NSNumber *routineId;`.

Comment: The `Property requires a protocol defining the contained type` error is only generated by Realm for a property of type `NSNumber` without a protocol annotating the expected concrete type. That means it cannot be generated for either of the model classes you mention. Have you checked to see whether you have another `routineId` property elsewhere that could be triggering this error?

Comment: @bdash you were right. I feel so stupid. I had a reference to that property on another object. If you want to put that in an answer, I'll accept. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Property requires a protocol defining the contained type error` is only generated by Realm for a property of type `NSNumber` without a protocol annotating the expected concrete type. That means it cannot be generated for either of the model classes you mention. It's likely you have a another `routineId` property elsewhere in your app that is triggering the error.

Comment: It is not correct.I checked through out the application whether I have same  property or another property elsewhere in app. I don't have another property but still I face the error.