# RLMException', reason: 'Property 'productos' requires a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

So I am using a Realm for my project, I have an object, 'Pedido' (spanish for order) that has many 'V3Producto' objects, as follows:

```
@interface V3Producto : RLMObject

@property NSString                  *codeProd; // Este es el código de barras!
@property NSString                  *codigo;
@property NSNumber<RLMDouble>       *descuento;
@property NSString                  *detailProd;
@property NSInteger     idid;
@property NSInteger     idCompania;
@property NSNumber<RLMDouble> *priceProd;
@property NSInteger     stock;

@property int      cantidadComprada;
@property int      cantidad; // cantidad de stock
```

And the code for the 'Pedidos' (orders)

@interface Pedido : RLMObject

```
@property NSNumber<RLMDouble>   *idUbicacion;
@property NSString              *fechaPedido;
@property NSString              *sucursal;
@property NSNumber<RLMDouble>   *filterId;
@property RLMArray<V3Producto*>       *productos;
```

When I run the app, as soon as it loads I get the error: 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'productos' requires a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray' which is quite strange since, before adding the RLMArray seemed to work just fine! Any V3Producto seems to be a perfectly fine and valid RLMObject! 
Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
I've tried renaming 'productos' to something else as other threads with the same name suggest but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realm Error: Property requires a protocol defining the contained type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851728/realm-error-property-requires-a-protocol-defining-the-contained-type)

Comment: I tried the solutions in that post but that didn't solve my problem @Koen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to declare a RLMArray, would be as follows:

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(V3Producto)

@interface Pedido : RLMObject

@property NSNumber<RLMDouble>   *idUbicacion;
...    
@property RLMArray<V3Producto*><V3Producto>       *productosPedido;
```

Note the I had to declare the type I want to use as an array with a MACRO (in the first line) and the declaration of the array is slightly different (you have to set the type plus the macro you've declared).

Answer (score 1):

This is because when declaring an RLMArray property, the type must be marked as conforming to a protocol by the same name as the objects it should contain according to [Realm Docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html)

Syntex to declare an RLMArray is :-

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ObjectType)
@property RLMArray<ObjectType *><ObjectType> *arrayOfObjectTypes;
```

Your code should be:-

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(V3Producto)

@interface Pedido : RLMObject
@property NSNumber <RLMDouble>   *idUbicacion;
@property NSString *fechaPedido;
@property NSString *sucursal;
@property NSNumber <RLMDouble> *filterId;
@property RLMArray <V3Producto*> <V3Producto> *productos;
@end
```